# Query is failing at date parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

```
  FROM apps.ap_suppliers aps          ,
  apps.ap_invoices_all ai              ,
  apps.ap_invoice_lines_all ail        ,
  apps.ap_invoice_distributions_all aid,
  apps.AP_DISTRIBUTION_SETS_all ads    ,
  apps.gl_code_combinations_kfv gcc    ,
  apps.ap_checks_all aca               ,
  apps.ap_invoice_payments_all aipa    ,
  apps.FND_TERRITORIES_TL ft
  WHERE aps.vendor_id            = ai.vendor_id
AND ai.invoice_id                = ail.invoice_id
AND ai.invoice_id                = aid.invoice_id
AND ail.invoice_id               = aid.invoice_id
AND ai.DISTRIBUTION_SET_ID       = ads.DISTRIBUTION_SET_ID(+)
AND aid.dist_code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id
AND aca.check_id                 = aipa.check_id
AND aipa.invoice_id              = ai.invoice_id
AND aca.vendor_id                = aps.vendor_id
AND aca.vendor_id                = ai.vendor_id
AND aca.COUNTRY                  = ft.TERRITORY_CODE
AND ai.invoice_id =nvl(p_invoice_id,ai.invoice_id)
AND ai.last_update_date BETWEEN NVL(p_from_date,ai.last_update_date)
AND NVL(p_to_date,sysdate+1);
```

last_update_date having the date like  11-JUN-16,
    so am passing the same.
    Query is failing at date parameter level(Data types are p_from_date Date,p_to_date Date). Query returning no result

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should stop using the old, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause. And use an explicit `JOIN` operator - _especially for outer joins_. Even Oracle recommends to do that (for outer joins)

Answer (score 0):

last_update_date is a date.  The data is not held as 11-JUN-16, it's held as a date.  When you pass in a string like '11-JUN-16' that might well be interpreted as 11/06/0016.  You won't have any invoices that old and that may well be why your query returns no data.

**Always** state the format when converting strings to dates.  And why not always use a four-digit year just to avoid ambiguity.  And finally use a numeric month - that way language is not an issue :

```
TO_DATE('11/06/2016','DD/MM/YYYY')
```